# jquery keydown doesn't work when i hit enter

Tags: jquery

I get nothing when i hit enter, doesn't work

The JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").keydown(function(e) {       
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {  
      $.post("server.php", { message: $("#message").val() },  function(data) { 
        $("#screen").val(data); 
        $("#message").val("");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The Html code:

```
<textarea id="screen" cols="40" rows="40"> </textarea> <br>  
<input id="message" size="40">
<button id="button"> Send </button>
```

Comment: When hitting enter make sure that you are having focus over the button

Comment: Maybe because this is inside a `form` and so pressing `enter` submit it

Comment: Works here - https://jsfiddle.net/1meyf3fh/1/ - tab onto the button and hit enter

Answer (score -1):

Use `keyup()` instead of `keydown()`